# Spring 4.2: CacheControl doesn't allow no-store and no-cache header

Tags: spring, spring-web

We are migrating a project from spring-web 4.1.8 to 4.2.3 and need to replace the deprecated code

```
WebContentInterceptor interceptor = new WebContentInterceptor();
interceptor.setCacheSeconds(0);
interceptor.setUseExpiresHeader(true);
interceptor.setUseCacheControlHeader(true);
interceptor.setUseCacheControlNoStore(true);
```

with the usage of the new `CacheControl` and `interceptor.setCacheControl(cacheControl)`.

But with the new API of `CacheControl`, you cannot use `noStore()` and `noCache()` together as these methods return a new `CacheControl` and aren't updating the existing ones.

Any idea, why this is the case and how the `Cache-Control` header can be set to `no-store, no-cache` using the new API?